# laravel 6 Eager Loading not working with load method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have two model **Product** and **Price**. relationship between two model is One to many.
each **product** has Many **Price** and each Price belong to one Product.

Eager Loading not working with  load method :

```
       $products=Product::all();
        $products->load("price");

        dd($products->toArray());
```

but below way working:

```
          $products=Product::all();

      foreach ($products as $product) {


          foreach ($product->price as $item) {

             }

      }


      dd($products->toArray());
```

all two ways work on Laravel 5.8

Relationships in Product Model:

```
  public function price()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Price::class,"product_id","id");
    }
```

Comment: how have you come to the conclusion that `load` has not lazy eager loaded all the prices for the Products?

Comment: sorry i can't understand your advice.

Comment: Can you post your relationships? What tagged version of `laravel/framework` are you on (check composer.lock)?

Comment: Laravel Framework 6.0.4 . i have  added relation in question body. relation work properly

Comment: when i use second way that  mentioned in question body i can get relation collections but i can't get relation using load method

Comment: Just tested on a fresh install of 6.0.4. Lazy eager loading seems to be working fine. So, either it's working fine in your app and your debugging is misleading you, or there is something in your app that is preventing it from working.

Comment: @patricus    thanks for your comment. but load method not working for me.